# Round 2: Derive this trig identity from the common ones? $\;\cos^2(3x) = \frac{1+\cos(6x)}{2}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$\cos^2(3x) = \frac{1+\cos(6x)}{2}$$

Just came across another wacky identity today. Is this an easy  derivation from the more popular identities, or is this one you just take it at face value and memorize?

Any hints to derive this one?

Comment: $\cos (2\alpha) = \cos^2\alpha - \sin^2\alpha = 2\cos^2\alpha - 1$. Set $\alpha = 3x$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Why not post that as an answer? I'd be happy to upvote it!

Comment: -1 : just set $x\mapsto 3x$ in your previuos question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a play off [your earlier question - Round One](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/567143/9003), where you found that $$\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos2x}{2}$$

In this case, put your "base angle" at $3x$, instead of $x$: $$\cos^2(3x)=\frac{1+\cos[2(3x)]}{2}$$

and you're done!

Recall the process:

$$\begin{align}\cos (6x) = \cos [2(3x)] & = \cos^2 (3x) - \sin^2 (3x) \\ \\ & = \cos^2 (3x) - \underbrace{(1 - \cos^2(3x))}_{ \large =\,\sin^2 (3x)} \\ &= 2\cos^2 (3x) - 1 \\ \\\iff \cos^2(3x) & =\dfrac{1 + \cos [2(3x)]}{2} = \dfrac{1 + \cos(6x)}2\end{align}$$

Comment: Looks like you handled Round 2 just fine! =1

Comment: Very nice explanation $\cong +100k$

Answer (score 0):

Hint is using $\cos(2y)=2\cos^2(y)-1$